# Devicemotion is not updating values

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cmmotionmanager

I am unable to figure out why the roll, pitch and yaw values are giving 0.0000 when logged.. I am sure it is a something that i miss but i cant figure it out..

This is the code:

```
//ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController (){

}
@property (nonatomic) CMMotionManager *motionManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    CMDeviceMotion *devMotion = [[CMDeviceMotion alloc]init];

    if ([self.motionManager isDeviceMotionAvailable]) {
        NSLog(@"Device Motion Available");
        [self.motionManager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval:1.0/30.0];
        // Pull mechanism is used
        [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
    }
    devMotion = self.motionManager.deviceMotion;

    NSLog(@"Roll Pitch and Yaw are %f, %f, %f",devMotion.attitude.roll, devMotion.attitude.pitch, devMotion.attitude.yaw);

}
```

I have gone thru this similar question: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605480/devicemotion-not-returning-anything-for-pitch-roll-or-yaw)

Please help me understand this..

Thanks..

---

**Updated Code:**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

    if ([self.motionManager isDeviceMotionAvailable]) {
        NSLog(@"Device Motion Available");
        [self.motionManager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval:1.0/30.0];
        // Pull mechanism is used
        [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
    }
    CMDeviceMotion *devMotion = self.motionManager.deviceMotion;
    NSLog(@"*Roll,Pitch and Yaw are %f, %f, %f",devMotion.attitude.roll, devMotion.attitude.pitch, devMotion.attitude.yaw);

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/30.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateValues:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) updateValues:(NSTimer *)timer{
    CMDeviceMotion *currDeviceMotion = self.motionManager.deviceMotion;

    NSLog(@"Roll Pitch and Yaw are %f, %f, %f",currDeviceMotion.attitude.roll, currDeviceMotion.attitude.pitch, currDeviceMotion.attitude.yaw);


}
```

This code also has a large part of its initial values as 0.000000 . After that it starts to get values... So i guess there is some delay for `startDeviceMotionUpdates` for providing values to `deviceMotion`. So looks like i need to figure out how to save the first non zero values.

Comment: Your updated code works as-is on my iPhone 4S. Are you using a device without a gyroscope (or the simulator)?

Comment: I am also using iPhone 4s, and it is working now.. Please read the statement below the code. :) What I said is that, the initial values are Zeros. After a while, it is logging non-zero values. But i wanted to get the values instantaneously, which seems to be difficult as devMotion variable won’t hold usable values (or any at all) right away as CMMotionManager takes a while to update the deviceMotion property after startDeviceMotionUpdates, as you said.

Comment: I think `currDeviceMotion` itself is `nil` while the gyroscope is starting up so you can just test for that.

Comment: Yes, I also think so.. I guess `currDeviceMotion` is nil while gyroscope starts and after a while it gets values. I think that solves the issue... Thanks pal... I really appreciate it... :)

Comment: It’s only `nil` as long as it has no values and it’s only non-`nil` when there are (reliable) values. So there is actually no guesswork involved here (you don’t have to compare the `float`s to zero using some tolerance or anything like that). It does not “get values” “after a while” because `nil` pointers can’t “get values”. It gets values when it stops being `nil`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40191/discussion-between-raphael-schweikert-and-iseeker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Notice that your `devMotion` variable won’t hold usable values (or any at all) right away as `CMMotionManager` takes a while to update the `deviceMotion` property after `startDeviceMotionUpdates`. So you should have some sort of timer that fires periodically and reads that property. Your linked article does something similar.

  - As long as the gyroscope is starting up, the `deviceMotion` property will be null (you’re only seeing 0.0 because messages to `nil` return zero).
- As a sidenote: your call to `[[CMDeviceMotion alloc] init]` is useless as you then override the variable the result was assigned to with `self.motionManager.deviceMotion`.

Comment: Thanks.. :) But I tried declaring it as strong and i am using ARC.. its not working. About the second point, i am already using a timer for this, i will update the question... and about the third.. could you make it clearer..

Comment: @iSeeker I’d need to see your timer handler code. Does the timer even fire (try putting an `NSLog` in there). About the last point: analyzing your code with Clang (Menu “Product” → “Analyze”) will show you this too (as a “Dead Store”).

Comment: Okay.. I understand that its not possible to get the deviceMotion values right away after the startDeviceMotionUpdates.. I guess that explains it.. Analyzing the code part is actually new to me... :) So will try that right away.. Also will update the question :)